# BASH: submenu with arrowkeys

Tags: linux, bash, menu, submenu, arrow-keys

I am currently trying to change [this script](https://top-scripts.blogspot.de/2011/01/blog-post.html) to a menu with submenus.
The problem is if I go in to a submenu the menu is not completely clearing. 
It replaces the single lines of the main menu with the entries of the submenu.

Do you know what I can change to make it work?

Here ist my last version

```
    #/bin/bash

E='echo -e';e='echo -en';trap "R;exit" 2
ESC=$( $e "\033")
TPUT(){ $e "\033[${1};${2}H";}
CL(){ $e "\033c";}
CIVIS(){ $e "\033[?25l";}
DRAW(){ $e "\033%@\033(0";}
WRITE(){ $e "\033(B";}
MARK(){ $e "\033[7m";}
UNMARK(){ $e "\033[27m";}
C(){ CL;}

    i=0;CL;CIVIS;NULL=/dev/null

ARROW(){ read -s -n3 key 2>/dev/null >&2
    if [[ $key = $ESC[A ]];then echo up;fi
    if [[ $key = $ESC[B ]];then echo dn;fi;}

POSITION(){ if [[ $cur = up ]];then ((i--));fi
    if [[ $cur = dn ]];then ((i++));fi
    if [[ i -lt 0   ]];then i=$LM;fi
    if [[ i -gt $LM ]];then i=0;fi;}

REFRESH(){ after=$((i+1)); before=$((i-1))
    if [[ $before -lt 0  ]];then before=$LM;fi
    if [[ $after -gt $LM ]];then after=0;fi
    if [[ $j -lt $i      ]];then UNMARK; M$before; else UNMARK; M$after;fi
    if [[ $after -eq 0   ]] || [[ $before -eq $LM ]];then
    UNMARK; M$before; M$after; fi; j=$i; UNMARK; M$before; M$after;}

M0(){ TPUT 3 4; $e "A) Firewall-Management & Gateway";}
M1(){ TPUT 4 4; $e "B) Bla bla bla";}

A0(){ TPUT 3 4; $e "1) Zweite Ebene";}
A1(){ TPUT 4 4; $e "2) Zweite Geile Ebene";}

MENU(){ LM=1; for each in $(seq 0 $LM);do M${each};done;}
INIT(){ MENU;}
SC(){ REFRESH;MARK;$S;cur=`ARROW`;}
ES(){ MARK;$e;read;INIT;};INIT

MENU2() {

    REFRESH(){ after=$((i+1)); before=$((i-1))
    if [[ $before -lt 0  ]];then before=$LM;fi
    if [[ $after -gt $LM ]];then after=0;fi
    if [[ $j -lt $i      ]];then UNMARK; A$before; else UNMARK; A$after;fi
    if [[ $after -eq 0   ]] || [[ $before -eq $LM ]];then
    UNMARK; A$before; A$after; fi; j=$i; UNMARK; A$before; A$after;}

    u_MENU() {
    LM=1; for each in $(seq 0 $LM);do A${each};done;}

    INIT(){ u_MENU;}
    SC(){ REFRESH;MARK;$S;cur=`ARROW`;}
    ES(){ MARK;$e;read;INIT;};INIT

while [[ "$O" != " " ]]; do case $i in
      0) S=A0;SC;if [[ $cur = "" ]];then C; exit 0;fi;;
      1) S=A1;SC;if [[ $cur = "" ]];then C; $e "a3:\n$(route -n )\n";ES;fi;;
        esac;POSITION;done
}

while [[ "$O" != " " ]]; do case $i in
      0) S=M0;SC;if [[ $cur = "" ]];then C; MENU2;ES;fi;;
      1) S=M1;SC;if [[ $cur = "" ]];then C;exit 0;ES;fi;;
esac;POSITION;done
```

Comment: You're missing the `}` for `MENU2()`. Should presumably go before the `while`.

Comment: Right, thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem. :-/

Comment: The problem is you are trying to reimplement `curses` in `bash`. Why not use a language that already has a library for this kind of terminal manipulation?

Comment: And why are you defining a function named `TPUT` instead of actually using the `tput` command?

Comment: @chepner how can you tell if curses exists on the system? and do you know how can I use it? do you have som usefull URLs?

TPUT implements e and tput together to make the script shorter.

Answer (score 0):

1)

`while` loop in `MENU2`:

```
-        esac;POSITION;C;done
+        esac;POSITION;done
```

Try setting the background back to blue. You'll see that the `C` seems to output newlines.

2)

`REFRESH` calls `M0`/`M1`/`M2`, so we need to add a new `REFRESH` in `MENU2` that calls `A0`/`A1`/`A2` instead:

```
REFRESH(){ after=$((i+1)); before=$((i-1))
        if [[ $before -lt 0  ]];then before=$LM;fi
        if [[ $after -gt $LM ]];then after=0;fi
        if [[ $j -lt $i      ]];then UNMARK; A$before; else UNMARK; A$after;fi
        if [[ $after -eq 0   ]] || [[ $before -eq $LM ]];then
        UNMARK; A$before; A$after; fi; j=$i; UNMARK; A$before; A$after;}
```

Comment: thanks sneep, that helps! but one thing, it erase not whole line. there a few rest signs from the first menu remain in the submenu at the line end

Comment: Can you edit your post again to make sure we've got the same code?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand the script:

The left arrow key and the ESC key should cancel the command, the submenu and return to the main menu. Likewise, it should also leave the main menu.

Do you have any idias for that?

I tried it next

1) Expand ARROW-Function to

```
ARROW(){ read -s -n3 key 2>/dev/null >&2
if [[ $key = $ESC[A ]];then echo up;fi
if [[ $key = $ESC[B ]];then echo dn;fi
if [[ $key = $ESC[C ]];then echo lf;fi;}
```

2) Expand POSITION-Function to

```
 POSITION(){ if [[ $cur = up ]];then ((i--));fi
 21     if [[ $cur = dn ]];then ((i++));fi
 22     if [[ $cur = lf ]];then break;fi
```

But that doesn't work as I thought ;-)

Comment: Hi, adding questions to your question like this makes it very unlikely that they'll be seen, and it's a huge coincidence that I'm seeing this at all :p

Comment: "Left" is `$ESC[D`. How about you just run your whole script again (by doing e.g. `if [[ $cur = lf ]];then exec /bin/bash $(realpath $0);fi`

Comment: In fact, you could put every menu into a different script. Maybe that'll keep readability up a bit.